# Intime and OutTime for the Modified date

Tags: sql

Question is already posted on June 4, but still am not get the proper answer.

Table Structure:

T_Person – Table 1

```
CARDNO 

168 
471 
488 
247 
519 
518 
331 
240 
518 
386 
441 
331
```

T_Cardevent – Table 2

```
CARDEVENTDATE CARDEVENTTIME 

20090225 163932
20090225 164630
20090225 165027
20090225 165137
20090225 165147
20090225 165715
20090225 165749
20090303 162059
20090303 162723
20090303 155029
20090303 155707
20090303 162824
```

Query

```
SELECT CARDNO,  CARDEVENTDATE, (1000000 * CAST (CARDEVENTDATE AS BIGINT) + CAST (CARDEVENTTIME AS BIGINT) - 30001) / 1000000 AS CardEvenDateAdjusted, CARDEVENTTIME
FROM T_CARDEVENT
WHERE (CARDEVENTDATE > 20090601)
GROUP BY CARDNO, CARDEVENTDATE, CARDEVENTTIME, (1000000 * CAST(CARDEVENTDATE AS BIGINT) + CAST(CARDEVENTTIME AS BIGINT) - 30001) / 1000000
ORDER BY CARDNO, CARDEVENDATEADJUSTED
```

From this above query date is displaying correctly according to that time 03:00:01 to 03:00:00

How can I get min (time) and Max (time) for the adjusted date?

I need the SQL query for the above condition.

Comment: If your previous question did not get the answer you wanted then you should be updating that question explaining why the answers you got are not helpful.  Asking the same question again will at best get the same answers but most likely get no answers at all.

Comment: Dave, I got the answer for date, but for the time not get. They replied on june 4 afterwards they are not replied. so that y posted again

Comment: Your last query is wrong as you are selecting values only from `T_Cardevent` table : `SELECT CARDNO, ... FROM T_CARDEVENT WHERE ... GROUP BY CARDNO ... ORDER BY CARDNO`. `CARDNO` column does not exists in your `T_Cardevent` table definition. Please update your question with the right query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the MIN/MAX from all the `CARDEVENTTIME` values :

```
SELECT MIN(CARDEVENTTIME)
     , MAX(CARDEVENTTIME)
  FROM T_Cardevent
```

Result :

```
MIN_CARDEVENTTIME MAX_CARDEVENTTIME
----------------- -----------------
155029            165749
```

or if you want them sorted by `CARDEVENTDATE` :

```
SELECT CARDEVENTDATE
     , MIN(CARDEVENTTIME) AS MIN_CARDEVENTTIME
     , MAX(CARDEVENTTIME) AS MAX_CARDEVENTTIME
  FROM T_Cardevent
 GROUP BY CARDEVENTDATE
```

Result :

```
CARDEVENTDATE MIN_CARDEVENTTIME MAX_CARDEVENTTIME
------------- ----------------- -----------------
20090225      163932            165749
20090303      155029            162824
```